# get in-depth hash-join info via sql (not trace files) e.g. # of passes, hash_area_size

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

I would be interested how much information about hash-joins can be retrieved without looking into trace files via event 10104. This is mainly about 11g, but I'd also be interested in case it works in 12c, but not 11g.

After a query was executed, for each hash-join of the query:

- Can I find out how big Oracle made the hash area for a particular hash-join of the query?
- Can I find out whether a particular hash-join went optimal or single-pass or multi-pass?

TYVM!

Comment: [V$SQL_WORKAREA_ACTIVE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-AA69DDA7-9A2A-4FF8-918A-387FCF684ABA.htm) maybe?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson this view and the surrounding ones seem to be exactly what I am looking for. Will play around with them and post queries here when I have them. TY!

Comment: Also V$TEMPSEG_USAGE can be useful - sql_id_tempseg gives you the SQL statement.